# Difference between inbreeding and interbreeding

Tags: terminology, reproductive-biology, sexual-reproduction

Is inbreeding the same as interbreeding?

On this site *interbreeding* is defined as (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interbreeding):

> 1. To breed with another kind or species; hybridize.
> 2. To breed within a narrow range or with closely related types or individuals; inbreed.

But I am sure that interbreeding is not the same as inbreeding. Inbreeding would be between genetically related members of a species and interbreeding would be between genetically un-related members of the same or different species.

after looking at wikepedia pages for both terms as well as searching the english oxford dictionar I am certain they are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically correct. Most common usage in my experience:

**[Inbreeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbreeding)** refers to sexual reproduction between genetically closely related individuals, within a species. Inbreeding will increase the relatedness between individuals in a population.

**[Interbreeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interbreeding)** refers to reproduction with another species (or race), and is often used as a synonym to *crossbreeding* or *hybridization* (when referring to hybrid offspring from two different species/races/breeds, not DNA hybridization). This is also how '*Interbreeding*' is defined in the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97546?redirectedFrom=interbreed#eid). However, '*Interbreeding*' is sometimes used just to signify that two individuals can breed and have viable offspring ("*...these two individuals can interbreed...*"), and under this usage this can also include/overlap with inbreeding.

The latter usage can be seen in the *Species* article in [Encyclopædia Britannica, online](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/558649/species?anchor=ref76052):

> **Species**, in biology, classification comprising related organisms that share common characteristics and are capable of interbreeding.
>   ...
>   Interbreeding only within the species is of great importance for evolution in that individuals of one species share a common gene pool that members of other species do not.

Answer (score -3):

interbreeding is a process in which same kind of species are breed together such as(male and female)but outer breeding is a process in which different kind of species are breed together such as(means horse is a specie it will breed with bitch those are different species